# Double to string with culture and only one decimal place

Tags: c#

I need to keep culture when converting double to string and also round to only one decimal place.

Converting double to string with culture:

```
((12275454.8).ToString("N", new CultureInfo("sl-SI")));
```

Gives output:

> 12.275.454,80

Converting double to string with only one decimal:

```
string.Format("{0:F1}",12275454.8)
```

Gives output:

> 12275454.8

The second output is without culture, the first output is not rounded to one decimal place. How to combine both methods?

Comment: Rounds to one decimal but without culture. Do you know where are all those letters explained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the format string of your second example in your first example, i.e.:

```
((12275454.8).ToString("N1", new CultureInfo("sl-SI")));
```

Edit: Changed format from F1 to N1 as per request. The difference between both is that N additionally uses thousands separators, whereas F does not. For details see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can set `"sl-SI"` culture as a *default* one:

```
 using System.Threading;

 ...

 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sl-SI");

 string test = string.Format("{0:F1}",12275454.8);
```

Add `try..finally` if you want `"sl-SI"` culture for a block of code only:

```
var savedCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

try {
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sl-SI");

  // Let's work with "sl-SI" for a while  
  string test = string.Format("{0:F1}",12275454.8);
  ...
}
finally {
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = savedCulture;
}
```